# Firebase RTDB: Call keepSynced while offline

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a Flutter app that uses Firebase RTDB. I'm a bit unclear on the mechanism of `keepSynced()`:

Our app creates new collections and adds data to these collections. The app also observes these collections to display the data. In the process, we call `keepSynced(true)` in order to keep the offline cache alive for these queries. Now we noticed that, when *creating a new collection* + calling `keepSynced(true)` *while offline*, the listener we register on the new collection doesn't receive data until the app goes online again. From then on, the caching and updating the listeners works as expected (online + offline).

So, in code:

```
// Execute this while offline:

// Enable permanent offline sync for a new node that doesn't exist yet on the Firebase server
await database.ref().child('new_node').keepSynced(true);

// Register listener
database.ref().child('new_node').onValue.listen((event) => print(event));

// Add data
database.ref().child('new_node/child').set({'key': 'value'});
```

The listener will trigger only after the device goes online.

The documentation on `keepSynced()` states

> By calling keepSynced(true) on a location, the data for that location will automatically be downloaded and kept in sync, even when no listeners are attached for that location. Additionally, while a location is kept synced, it will not be evicted from the persistent disk cache.

So is it actually required to be connected with the Firebase backend ("will automatically be downloaded") while calling `keepSynced()` in order for the offline caching/querying to work?

Comment: Hmmm.... the local `onValue` listener should fire immediately for the local write, regardless of whether you called `keepSynced` on the node. There are some possible edge cases (for example, when the SDK can't know if it's seeing the complete node), but you shouldn't be hitting those with the code you shared. Are you saying that the behavior is different when you *don't* call `keepSynced(true)` on the reference?

Comment: No, calling `keepSynced(true)` actually makes no difference.

Comment: Wait, turns out I dumbed down the example code in my question too much. What we actually do is write to a child node of the observed/cached node. I just tested: When writing to `new_node`, it works, if wrinting to `new_node/child`, it doesn't. I edited the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `keepSynced` at any moment, but the client will only be able to download the data from the server when it is connected to the server.

If that is not the behavior you're observing, please edit your question to include a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

---

**Update** based on the new repro in your question:

The behavior you're seeing is unfortunate, but expected.

The Firebase API guarantees (undocumented these days) that it will never surface a partial node to your app. Since you're only setting `/new_node/child`, and it has no knowledge of the current state of `/new_node`, it doesn't raise a `value` event on `new_node` since in only has partial information about that node.

If you were to instead listen for `child_added` on `new_node`, the SDK would raise an event in this scenario - but it won't raise a value event since until it can ascertain that it has a complete snapshot of `new_node`.

The two most common paths forward are:

- Listen at a lower level in your JSON tree, for example by listening to `child_*` events (as mentioned above).
- Perform an initial write operation on all of `new_node`, so that the local SDK knows what the expected initial state of the node is against it can then perform the lower-level writes. You could possibly then use security rules to reject this priming write operation on the server if there is also data that can't be wiped.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is whether it is per design *required* to connect to the server once and "download" the data for a new, offline-created collection to be accessible from the local cache?

Comment: Local writes should be visible on the local client right away, but a lot depends on the exact (sequence of) API calls that you do, which is why I asked for a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the behavior you're asking about.